# How to replace all null values with 'N/A' in a sqlite table

Tags: sqlite, null

I have a big sqlite table and I want to output it into a file. So I want all the null value to be shown as string 'N/A' in the file. How to achieve this by sqlite query?
Thanks.

Comment: The `CASE ...` expression and `ISNULL` are helpful for that

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the `ifnull` function as:

```
select ifnull(mycolumn, 'N/A') from mytable;
```

From the sqllite.org (http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html):

> The ifnull() function returns a copy of its first non-NULL argument,
>   or NULL if both arguments are NULL. Ifnull() must have exactly 2
>   arguments. The ifnull() function is equivalent to coalesce() with two
>   arguments.

I don't think can do something like `select ifnull(*, 'N/A') from mytable;`, so you will have to list all the columns explicitly.

Here is something you can use to generate a `csv` output:

```
sqlite> .mode csv
sqlite> .output myoutput.csv
sqlite> select ifnull(mycolumn1, 'N/A'), ifnull(mycolumn2, 'N/A') from mytable;
```